# Bash shell script to remove a guid within a filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, string

I'm trying to replace a guid without hyphens from some file names.

I have the regex done, I think, however I can't seem to get either the escaping correct or the replacement commands to work with each other.

Here's my regex

https://regex101.com/r/SiqsjP/1

```
(-[0-9a-f]{32})
```

With file names like this

iPhone6Plus-learn_multi_child-0dfb2dc71fe20da66ca47190d3136b12.png

I've seen this answer [Bash shell script to locate and remove substring within a filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19166/bash-shell-script-to-locate-and-remove-substring-within-a-filename) but it's not quite the same...

I think this should work, but it doesn't complain of an error ?

```
newname=`echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/\([0-9a-f]{32}\)\.png/\1.png/'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string manipulations in the shell:

```
for name in *.png; do
    # remove everything after the last '-' including the dash
    # and add the '.png' extension back
    newname="${name%-*}.png"
    echo mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

This assumes that all files that you'd like to rename are `.png` files in the current directory.

Run this once and remove the `echo` if it seems like it's doing the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

In ***sed*** *BRE* (basic regular expressions) you should also escape curly braces `{}`:

```
newname=`echo "$filename" | sed 's/-[0-9a-f]\{32\}//g'`
```

To move/rename the file:

```
mv "$filename" "$newname"
```

Comment: Thanks, although again this doesn't produce an error, that doesn't rename the files

Comment: your command doesn't rename the file at all. It was a substitution. You should deal with `mv` command additionally

Comment: should that be piped also?

Comment: @Jules, no, line by line, see my update.

Comment: Do I need for around it?